# Fanfiction about Draco and Harry switching bodies after a Polyjuice accident

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

There’s this one fanfiction I read where Draco and Harry each drank Polyjuice and got stuck as each other.

I can’t remember the name, but I believe it was a series. I’m pretty sure each book started with the word Draco.

Comment: I support fanfic questions, but this one is pretty bare on details. If Laurel got it right, you can accept their answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Is this [*The Draco Trilogy*](https://web.archive.org/web/20070204034643/http://www.heidi8.com/dt/)? [One source](https://pokey1984.livejournal.com/9186.html) describes it thusly:

> The Draco Trilogy by Cassandra Claire
>   Word total 896,762 (Harry and Draco end up in each other's bodies semi-permanently after using a botched Polyjuice potion in class, only no one else knows.)

It has three books with titles starting with "Draco" (the trilogy) and two others that don't:

- Draco Dormiens
- Draco Sinister
- Draco Veritas
- Something Impossible
- A Lot to Be Upset About